# Handling NA and NAN in R

Tags: r, na

I am attempting to run a simple simulation of 100,000 instances for the code below. When attempting to get the sd and mean of of dlogP I am receiving sd(dlogP):NA and mean(dlogP): NaN. I believe i should be getting a sd deviation similar to that of the original rnorm of 5% Can someone help me out as what I am doing incorrectly? I have attempted to adjust the number of iterations which seems to work, but I need to generate 100,000 instances. Thanks in advance.

```
set.seed(2013)
P_1 <- 100               # Initial price of stock
r <- rnorm(100000, .01, .05) # Generating 100,000 instances
P <- P_1*cumprod(1+r)        
set.seed(2013)
logP<- log(P)
dlogP <-log1p(P)-logP    # The change in logs from t+1 and t
dlogP 
head(dlogP,1)            # Will output the first value of the matrix
sd(dlogP)
mean(dlogP)
plot(P)
```

Comment: Inspect `tail(P)`. Sequence (1+r)^n is very explosive so that it reaches `Inf` quickly

Comment: I already answered you on a previous question why it is unrealistic to have a `1%` return from one day to another. This quantity is an annualized quantity, so you need to divide it by the number of trading days (rough approximation not depending on the stock calendar is `252` days in a year) since you run your simulation on a daily basis.
Hence, of course, you obtain something which explodes after `100 000` simulations.
The problem is not the code, but having an understanding of the kind of simulation to achieve.

Comment: You probably want  `sd( dlogP[is.finite(dlogP)])`. If you wanted to know the first period at which the sequence exceeded the numerical capacity you might use `which`.

Comment: I'd like to buy this stock!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on 1% daily return, you could do it in log scale, without touching `Inf`.

```
set.seed(2013)
P_1 <- 100               # Initial price of stock
r <- rnorm(100000, .01, .05) # Generating 100,000 instances 
logP <- log(P_1) + cumsum(log(1+r))
dlogP <-diff(logP)    # The change in logs from t+1 and t
#dlogP 
head(dlogP,1)            # Will output the first value of the matrix
sd(dlogP)
mean(dlogP)
```

Comment: I do not consider this as an answer. You assume something false, and try to propose a solution which is even more false. It is like trying to fill a box full of holes with water :) The target is to help people of having a better understanding of what they are doing, and taking distance on the real content when there are mistakes!